# Symfony2/Doctrine2: OrderBy count of another Entity (ManytoOne)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have Entity 1: `Upload` , it has a `oneToMany` relationship to `comments`

i have a custom respository for Upload, and i want to find the most commented uploads.

so when i do

```
/**
 * @param $sortBy String
 * @param $limit Int
 */
public function getWeekTopUploads($sortBy,$limit){



    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->add('select', 'u')
        ->add('from', 'TrackerMembersBundle:Upload u')
        // ->where('u.created')
        ->orderBy('u.comments', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults( $limit );


    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;



}
```

i get the error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 55 near 'comments DES': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

it seems not to want to accept ordering by number of comments, how can i solve this or what would be the proper re-write for the query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass 'u' as param to your createQueryBuilder() function, and declare your getWeekTopUploads() function in your UploadRepository:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        ->where('u.created' >= new \DateTime("1 week ago"))
        ->orderBy('u.comments', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

return $qb;
```

Comment: i do not get how your code example, solves my question....you mean add comments in your variable $from ?

Comment: I edited my answer. First, make sure to put your function in your UploadRepository, where you store all your custom queries related to Upload. Then try my code above, I may made typos but the spirit is here.